# Do English speakers tend to use verbs in passive form?

Tags: passive-voice

Is my understanding true that English speakers tend to use passive instead of active form of verbs?

Compare these:

> *Let's do it* 
> **Let's get it done**
>
> *I will cook it* 
> **I will get it cooked**
>
> *Starting* 
> **Getting Started** (mostly seen in the beginning of tutorials)

Comment: What gives you that impression? Radio? Movies?

Comment: People use both active and passive forms in general, as you know; so, if I had to answer your question literally, it would be unanswerable. But I suspect that you mean something else; you probably find it interesting that we can use "let's get it done" to say that we will do it ourselves, whereas one would expect "get something -ed" to mean that we have someone else do it—correct? If so, could you edit your question to better reflect what you really mean, and what kind of answer you expect? Now it is a bit vague.

Comment: Hi Meysam. As Cerberus says, feel free to clarify what you actually mean. In its current form the question is rather broad and vague. If you can boil it down to something *specific*, and provide *evidence* that people actually do prefer X over Y, then it can be reopened.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 Hi. Yes I agree that my question is a little broad and vague. Just didn't know how to ask a better question. Maybe I will rephrase it in future.

Answer (score 2):

For the first example it seems that "let's do it" is more popular than the passive version:

[image]

(from [Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Let%27s+do+it%2C+Let%27s+get+it+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3))

But that doesn't say anything about active and passive in general.

Comment: I'm not even sure *"Let's get it done"* really is "passive voice". It may be contracted to *"'s"*, but *"we"* (in the form of *"us"*) are certainly present there. *"Let it be done"* would definitely be passive voice though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the opposite: English speakers tend to avoid the passive. Teachers of English routinely discourage use of passives on the ground that they are weak and ambiguous. "It will get done." Who will do it? Why won't you say?

The passive has become associated with weaseling politicians. It's a standing joke these days that a politician caught in corruption or some other scandal, instead of saying, "Yes, I did wrong and I beg forgiveness," will say -- and this has become a stock phrase -- "Mistakes were made." Like, wow, a crime just committed itself, I was so surprised when I saw it happen.

You do often see the passive in instructions of various kinds. Instead of saying, "You should now add butter to the pan" or "Add  butter to the pan now", they will say, "Butter should now be added to the pan." That's probably the most common accepted use in English.